# How to fetch all erc20 transactions for particular contracts using http or wss?

Tags: python, rpc, web3py

When I am using node to fetch, not every contract has hex "Transfer", some have others like "Swap".

I have tried some code it's mostly working fine, but no response for some contracts as explained above.

```py
checksum_address = web3.toChecksumAddress(erc_20_contract)
logs_topics = [
    '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
]

filter = {
            'fromBlock': int(start_block),
            'toBlock': int(end_block),
            'address': checksum_address,
            'topics': logs_topics
        }

raw_logs = web3.eth.get_logs(filter)
```

Comment: The `web3` tag description begins with "Do not use this tag". Please replace it as suggested there.

Comment: I do not see any get_logs in the doc for web3js. Also, scanning the chain from start to end may take a long (looooong) time.

Comment: Are you using node.js or python? If you're using node.js, why is this tagged `python`?

Comment: No i am using python please see, might be looks like js but its not..